# Webscraping from a png

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, png

I am trying to retrieve informations from this website https://www.snow-forecast.com/resorts/PozzaDiFassa/history, from the graph "Average Snow Conditions in", to have the snow type level for each week.

I tried to use BeautifulSoup to retrieve different level of the graph but they all came up empty except this one:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")                                     
div = soup.find('div', {"id" : "bluebird"})
div
```

which gives:

```
<div id="bluebird"><img alt="Average Snow Conditions in Pozza di Fassa Graph. (Updated on: 2021-07-11)" src="/system/charts-png/PozzaDiFassa/bluebird.png"/></div>
```

Whenever I tried to retrieve lower levels, "div" comes back empty. I am gessing it must be link to the fact that the graph is a png. How must I do it then ?

Thank you in advance for help !

Comment: What exactly you are trying to find from that graph can you specify more information please!

Answer (score 1):

You can't webscrape information from an image, that's just a grid of pixels (colors). But the *"Average Snow Conditions in..."* graph is not an image, it's not a png, it's drawn in pure HTML using SVG.

If you go to Developer's Tools in Firefox (Ctrl-Shift-i), right-click on the graph then select *Inspect Element*, you'll see the `<div id="bluebird">` element, and underneath it there are no other `<div>` elements. Instead, there's an `<svg>` element, and several `<g>` (group) elements, and `<rect>` (rectangle) elements. There you can find the geometry of the rectangles that comprise the graph. Unfortunately, that does not give you the actual data you're looking for (although you might be able to reconstruct it from the rectangle geometry).

If what you're trying to retrieve is the number of days in each category (powder, bluebird, etc), that is displayed in a popup, but only when you right-click a column in the graph, so again, it's not all there for you to webscrape.

You could try the following: use a tool like **selenium** to programmatically right-click each column. At that point, the popup exists in the DOM tree as a `<div class="hint">` element (again, see the dev tools), with one "hint__row" for each of the categories, and a "hint__value" element that has exactly what you want. Not easy, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

The target path was in image node

```
src ="/system/charts-png/PozzaDiFassa/bluebird.png"
```

You can combine with web domain like

```
https://www.snow-forecast.com/system/charts-png/PozzaDiFassa/bluebird.png
```

I think this was your want image url path

Comment: I am not trying to retrieve the image but the informations in it (which we can access on the website so I am pretty sure it is possible).

Answer (score 0):

use to get the link list
`img_list = [x.get('src') for x in soup.select(img_selector)]`

then you can below to save image in your directory

```
if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
            for i in contents:
                r = requests.get(i[1], headers=headers)
                with open(i[0], "wb")as f:
                    f.write(r.content)
            print("--- finished {}---".format(len(os.listdir(path))))
```